# Postfix: fatal:unsupported map type for this operation: hash

Tags: email, configuration, fatal-error, raspbian, postfix-mta

I am trying to configure postfix on my Raspberry Pi (OS: Raspbian).

I get this Fatal Error Message when I try to execute following commands:

- postmap
- newaliases

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause was that Berkeley DB support is needed.

For the Raspberry Pi I don't see any option for Berkeley DB. After I installed postfix it just worked.  I know this post is old, but in case it helps anyone:  Perhaps re-installing postfix-lmdb or postfix-cdb would be the fix needed on a Pi.

For anyone using Gentoo Linux, add "mail-mta/postfix berkdb" to /etc/portage/package.use or a file inside that if it is a directory, then recompile postfix.